# How to use an application helper method in an email template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have defined a helper in the `ApplicationHelper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def url_for_portal
    URI("https://example.com/")
  end
end
```

And want to use it in a mail template, `app/views/client_mailer/account_activation.md.erb`, but get an `undefined method 'url_for_portal'`:

```
Activate your Example.com account by clicking on the link below:
[<%= url_for_portal %>](<%= url_for_portal %>)
```

How can I write and use helper methods in mail templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `helper :application` to your `ClientMailer` class.